# Android HTTP URL Connection throwing IOException from getResponseCode

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, ioexception

I am trying to do a GET on an URL and I see the following behavior that is consistent and reproducible everytime.

1. When I am on my LTE connection from my carrier, everything works perfectly without any issues.
2. Whenever I switch to my wifi connection at work, I get an IO Exception from `getResponseCode`. (Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer) ).
3. The wi-fi at work is setup to go through a firewall and a login mechanism. So, I thought that this might have something to do with it (even though the login session is valid for about 2 days. so, once logged in from the device there should not be any issues). But, even with the work wi-fi, if I just try to get the URL contents directly from the browser on the device, it retrieves the page just fine (the rest api just returns a very small and simple json formatted body). So, this is not due to any connection issue from the device to the server.
4. Also, from the same app, I have tried loading that page using a webview instead of an api call and that loads just fine.

I have tried to set keep-alive to be false (as suggested in another question) and that doesn't help.

Edit: Posting the code for my main `getJSon` method:

```
public static String getJSON(String url, int timeout) {
    HttpURLConnection c = null;
    try {
        URL u = new URL(url);
        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
        c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();

        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        String cookie = cookieManager.getCookie(u.getHost());
        c.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);

        if(cookie == null || cookie.isEmpty()) {
            Log.i(TAG,"No authentication cookie. Not trying to GET from the self api.");
            return ""; //No authentication cookie. GET call will fail.
        }

        c.setRequestMethod("GET");
        c.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "0");
        c.setUseCaches(false);
        c.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        c.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
        c.setReadTimeout(timeout);
        c.connect();
        int status = c.getResponseCode();
        Log.i(TAG,"Status Code in getJSON:" + status);
        switch (status) {
            case 200:
            case 201:
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                br.close();
                return sb.toString();
            default:
                Log.e(TAG,"Failure retrieving contents from URL:"+ url +" HTTP code:" + status);
                return "";
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        Log.e(TAG,"Malformed URL:" + url);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.e(TAG,"IOException when retrieving user data from URL");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (c != null) {
            try {
                c.disconnect();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e(TAG,"Exception when disconnecting url resource when retrieving user data from URL.");
            }
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

**Exception stack trace:**

```
05-19 10:20:30.154  18528-20770/com.example W/System.err﹕ java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
05-19 10:20:30.165  18528-20770/com.example W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterRecvfrom(IoBridge.java:592)
05-19 10:20:30.165  18528-20770/com.example W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:556)
05-19 10:20:30.165  18528-20770/com.example W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:485)
05-19 10:20:30.165  18528-20770/com.example W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:37)
05-19 10:20:30.165  18528-20770/com.example W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:237)
05-19 10:20:30.165  18528-20770/com.example W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:113)
05-19 10:20:30.165  18528-20770/com.example W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:147)
05-19 10:20:30.166  18528-20770/com.example W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:94)
05-19 10:20:30.166  18528-20770/com.example W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:175)
05-19 10:20:30.166  18528-20770/com.example W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:101)
05-19 10:20:30.166  18528-20770/com.example W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:616)
05-19 10:20:30.166  18528-20770/com.example W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:379)
05-19 10:20:30.166  18528-20770/com.example W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:323)
05-19 10:20:30.166  18528-20770/com.example W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:491)
05-19 10:20:30.166  18528-20770/com.example W/System.err﹕ at com.example.ConnectionHelper.getJSON(ConnectionHelper.java:98)
05-19 10:20:30.166  18528-20770/com.example W/System.err﹕ at com.example.RegistrationHelper.retrieveAndStoreUserData(RegistrationHelper.java:296)
05-19 10:20:30.166  18528-20770/com.example W/System.err﹕ at com.example.RegistrationHelper.registerDeviceWithBackend(RegistrationHelper.java:444)
05-19 10:20:30.166  18528-20770/com.example W/System.err﹕ at com.example.RegistrationHelper.access$400(RegistrationHelper.java:31)
05-19 10:20:30.166  18528-20770/com.example W/System.err﹕ at com.example.RegistrationHelper$1.doInBackground(RegistrationHelper.java:197)
05-19 10:20:30.166  18528-20770/com.example W/System.err﹕ at com.eclinic247.www.eclinicdr.RegistrationHelper$1.doInBackground(RegistrationHelper.java:177)
05-19 10:20:30.166  18528-20770/com.example W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
05-19 10:20:30.166  18528-20770/com.example W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
05-19 10:20:30.166  18528-20770/com.example W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
05-19 10:20:30.166  18528-20770/com.example W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
05-19 10:20:30.166  18528-20770/com.example W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
05-19 10:20:30.166  18528-20770/com.example W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
05-19 10:20:30.166  18528-20770/com.example W/System.err﹕ Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
05-19 10:20:30.167  18528-20770/com.example W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.recvfromBytes(Native Method)
05-19 10:20:30.167  18528-20770/com.example W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.recvfrom(Posix.java:161)
05-19 10:20:30.167  18528-20770/com.example W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:250)
05-19 10:20:30.167  18528-20770/com.example W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:553)
05-19 10:20:30.167  18528-20770/com.example W/System.err﹕ ... 24 more
```

Comment: Don't you think you should show your code?

Comment: please post the code so that we can look into it

Comment: Code looks ok. Try without the Content-length property.

Comment: Tried it. Did not make any difference. Same behavior continues (works fine on carrier network connection, throws exception when connected to office wi-fi).

Comment: Since there are no answers, I wanted to post the solution I found myself, to this issue. This was because of a firewall setting on the corporate wifi. Figured that out through comparing headers of requests originating from the browser on the device and the app/native call. And since the webview calls were going through on the browser, I decided to use the User-Agent string used by webview and set this on my get/post requests using httpurlconnection. Now it worked without any issues.